# SSH host key has changed after VM switched node, can't login

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, ssh-keys

I have a server in a cloud service that has been running smoothly. I've only ever connected via SSH.

Yesterday, they had a node malfunction and moved all VM:s to another node/other nodes. After the outage, I could not connect and gave me the host change warning. I figured it had to do with the outage, so I removed the key and tried connecting with the password, which also surprisingly failed. I know what you're thinking, I immediately turned the machine off from the service control panel in case someone unauthorized had gained access and changed the password.

After this I did the only logical thing I could think of and restored a snapshot of the server from when I knew it worked. Yet, the result is the same. I can't connect with the key and the password login doesn't work. How is this possible? Even assuming someone else has gained access to the server, it makes no sense why I can't login to an instance created from a snapshot when logging in definitely worked!

I've obviously contacted the service's customer support, but I don't expect an answer until tomorrow. I'm also curious as to what the hell is going on?

Comment: Check if your server's IP address changed. In future, DO NOT ignore the warning from ssh or delete the key from known_hosts until you are 100% sure you have identified and solved the problem. This could have saved you from a whole lot of malicious activity, but only if you don't go charging blindly in. At this point your safest bet is to restore from backups.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the reply. I will definitely check the actual IP, though it says it's the same in the control panel. I'm just guessing, but could firewall settings on the new node also cause a problem?
And yeah, it was stupid to remove the key and try to log in with the password. Whatever happened I'm going to change the password just to be safe.